# Dead Roo Project (Unresponsive Shell)

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-roo

I've been working with a Roo project for a while but now when I type a command into the Roo shell, I don't get anything at all, although the CPU usage seems to go very high.

Seen similar problems on here and tried various suggested fixes such as:

Deleting the bgp (I think) file in my home directory (Win 7)
Deleting the entire .m2 maven repository folder
Upgrading to STS 2.9.1
Deleting various cache folders/files in Roo's root folder (sts-cache-)
Opening/cleaning my project a million times

There's nothing coming out in the log file (.log in my workspace metadata folder).

At a loss as to what to do now. If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Can you report back after verifying your disks are working fine?

Comment: Hi, will do. Although, I'm experiencing the same problem on two different machines for the same project. I don't think there are any disk errors, but I will check (will be tonight though). If there are any other cache/build files etc that I might have missed but could be deleted to kick-start it again please let me know.

Comment: I just tried it on a third machine and I still get the same problem. I'll still check the disks for errors tonight but (I'm guessing) it's looking more likely that it's a problem with the project?

Comment: Actually, if I create a new Roo project it works fine. So I think it's definately a problem with my project. I'll start stripping things out and see if I can get it working

Comment: Maybe the Project Name or the initial setup has something to do with this issue. If this continues to happen, please file a bug in the Spring Roo Issue Tracker.

Comment: Also, I noticed that once I open the Roo shell on my project, the CPU jumps to around 25-45% and stays there even if it's not doing anything. However opening a Roo shell on my new blank project, the CPU settles back to 0% after a couple of seconds.

Comment: Will do bhagyas, I'll see if I can find any log files anywhere with some info I can post

Comment: Its seems to be working now. I entered a command (finder list) and waited for some time and eventually it responded. I also got 'At this time you have not authorized Spring Roo to download resources from VMware domains' but that was after I issued another command. So I have also entered 'download accept terms of use' into the shell. Whether just waiting, or accepting the terms of use fixed it I'm not sure but it's much more responsive now. I'll try and recreate on my other machine later

Comment: Hmm, well I have checked my project out again and rebuilt it from scratch. Because I upgraded to STS 2.9.1 some of my maven deps were wrong so I corrected them. Now the Roo shell is responding a bit better but it's still in a bad way because it's not recognising any of my entities e.g. Cannot provide finders because 'com.myproject.domain.Person' is not an entity. Any ideas? I've not got any 'Problems' any more and no build errors.

Comment: Is the same thing happening with both the Standalone Roo Console and the STS Roo console?

Comment: I will try that tonight but I might not get chance to work on it for a few days now. If I get anywhere I'll post back.

Answer (score 0):

When the size of the project gets big, Spring Roo does take a lot of time in building class files.

A few things you can do :

Please make sure that in the STS settings, auto build is disabled. Only build when it's needed.
How does your memody graph go? Try to tweak the memory in the STS.ini.